# What did the Dark Prophecy in Towers of Midnight mean?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

**Warning:** Spoilers for A Memory of Light under spoiler text.

The Dark Prophecy that Moridin shows to Graendal in *Towers of Midnight* was:

> Lo, it shall come upon the world that the prison of the Greatest One
>   shall grow weak, like the limbs of those who crafted it. Once again,
>   His 
> glorious cloak shall smother the Pattern of all things, and the
>   Great
>  Lord shall stretch forth His hand to claim what is His. The
>   rebellious
>  nations shall be laid barren, their children caused to
>   weep. There shall
>  be none but Him, and those who have turned their
>   eyes to His majesty.
>
> In that day, when the One-Eyed Fool travels the halls of mourning,
>   and
>  the First Among Vermin lifts his hand to bring freedom to Him who
>   will Destroy, the last days of the Fallen Blacksmith's pride shall
>   come.
>  Yea, and the Broken Wolf, the one whom Death has known, shall
>   fall and
>  be consumed by the Midnight Towers. And his destruction
>   shall bring
>  fear and sorrow to the hearts of men, and shall shake
>   their very will itself.
>
> And then shall the Lord of the Evening come. And He shall take our
>   eyes, for our souls shall bow before Him, and he shall take our skin,
>   for
>  our flesh shall serve Him, and He shall take our lips, for only
>   Him will
>  we praise. And the Lord of the Evening shall face the Broken
>   Champion,
>  and shall spill his blood and bring us the Darkness so
>   beautiful. Let the 
> screams begin, O followers of the Shadow. Beg for
>   your destruction!
>   <sub>Towers of Midnight, Epilouge</sub>

What was the meaning?

I think the obvious interpretations are:

- "Greatest One" \ "Great Lord" \ "Lord of the Evening" = Shai'tan
- One Eyed Fool = Mat

> - First Among Vermin = Logain, as he broke the seals.

- Fallen Blacksmith = Perrin
- Broken Champion = Rand

The main mysteries come in the middle paragraph.

What were the halls of mourning?

Who was the Broken Wolf, who Death had known?

> [Rodel Ituralde](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Rodel_Ituralde), nicknamed "The Wolf" / "Little Wolf". How had Death known him?

Was "Midnight Towers" a reference to the Forsaken?

Comment: Damn, there are Memory of Light spoilers in there, it's not obvious as you're refering only to Towers of Midnight.

Comment: @jv42 I'm sorry if you hit a spoiler. The question is tagged "a memory of light" and it's at the very end of Towers, and anything from Memory was spoiler tagged so I thought that would be enough. I've now added a warning at the top. Tho looking at Wheel of Time questions (especially ones related to prophecies) and reading spoiler text probably isn't the best way to stay spoiler free...

Comment: Yes, it was my fault for not reading the tag, but thanks for adding the textual warning.

Comment: The Broken wolf is Hopper, Perin's wolf friend who died but was still present in the wolf dream until killed again in the wolf dream by Skinner/Luc and so fell again

Comment: @dai i agree the broken wolf is hopper in my mind. interview number 12 seems to confirm hopper is indeed in this prophecy http://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=dark+prophecy

Comment: lord of the evening is probably ishamel/moridin due to lews theron being lord of the morning, so his counterpoint would be lord of the evening.